# Can you tell if a group is Fuchsian from its presentation?

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

I have been learning about Fuchsian groups, and from what I understand (based on the notes here: [https://math.la.asu.edu/~paupert/CriderPoincarePolygonTheorem.pdf](https://math.la.asu.edu/%7Epaupert/CriderPoincarePolygonTheorem.pdf)), there is a group of symmetries of the hyperbolic plane generating a regular octagonal tiling with presentation

$$
\langle g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4 \mid g_4^{-1}g_3^{-1}g_4g_3g_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}g_2g_1=1\rangle.
$$

I decided to search numerically for subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ with this presentation, and found elements $g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4$ satisfying the relation above but which did not appear to be Fuchsian (I plotted the orbit of a point and saw that as I went to longer words, the orbit seemed to get dense).

If my numerics and my understanding is correct, this means it might be possible to have two groups $G,G'\subset SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ such that $G$ is Fuchsian and $G'$ is isomorphic to $G$ (as a group), but $G'$ is not Fuchsian.  Is this correct, or have I made a mistake?

In other words, to state the question cleanly:
**Is it possible to find two groups** $G,G'\subset SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ **with the same presentation, such that $G$ is Fuchsian and $G'$ is not?**

Comment: Yes, this is completely possible. Note also that your numerics do (and cannot) not ensure faithfulness of the representation.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  What do you mean when you say "faithfulness of the representation"?

Comment: Faithful means injective.

Comment: I see, so it might be the case that the generators I find numerically satisfy additional relations.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Right, this can easily happen.